# Cloud Formation help Availability zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Hi Looking to understand what the bellow 2 cloudrormation statements do,  Please explain what 0 and 1 indicates here.

```
  AvailabilityZone:
    'Fn::Select':
      - 0
      - 'Fn::GetAZs':
          Ref: 'AWS::Region'

  AvailabilityZone:
    'Fn::Select':
      - 1
      - 'Fn::GetAZs':
          Ref: 'AWS::Region'
```

Answer (score 1):

`Fn::GetAZs` returns a **list** of AZs, e.g `[AZ1, AZ2, AZ3]`. `0` and `1` will take **first** and the **second** elements from the list respectively.